# Selecting data from a dataset using information from another dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am trying to calculate animal home ranges using movement data from the 30 days before two animals encountered each other, using R. So, for example, if animal1 meets animal2 on the 15th of June, I would like to select all movement data available between the 16th of May and the 14th of June for each animal. The problem I have is that I do not know how to program the subsetting of the movement data based on the date and animal id.

I would like to end up with two new datasets of movement data for each encounter, one per animal. Each new dataset would contain all movement data recorded for one of the encountering animals in the 30 days before the encounter.

I share part of the data with you in this [Wetransfer link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bbced8bc78c7d1c14fd8cf3a3957c31520220901175802/081608/preview/d5a55cd2a7e14a8ebc8686a858fe606a20220901180141) . The workbook contains 2 tabs:

encounters: Contains one line per encounter, with a column for the
date, another with the ID of group1 A and another with the ID of
group2. I would use the date and the IDs of this dataset to select
the data from the other dataset (movement_data)

movement_data: Contains one line per GPS point collected. There are
columns for the id of the point, the ID of the group, the date in
with the GPS point was taken, the latitude and the longitude.

Does anybody know how to do this? I don't even know where to start

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So to subset by the id of the animal, you would just need to use DPLYR to subset the data by ID:

```
data %>% filter(ID == "A")
```

To get the dates you could add a column in excel where you subtract 30 days from each encounter and then filter for dates between that column and the encounter date

```
data %>% 
filter(ID == "A") %>%   
filter(between(date_column, as.Date('YYYY-MM-DD'), as.Date('YYYY-MM-DD')))
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. Nevertheless, the key issue is to use the data in another dataset to automize the process you describe. Otherwise, that coding would need to be repeated hundreds of times manually.